# HTML+CSS generated .pdf file has different layout on different computers?

Tags: html, css, pdf, node-html-pdf

I managed to generate a .pdf file using HTML and CSS.
The size of the page is predefined in inches (A4 format). It works great on my computer, but when I run the program on a different computer, the generated file looks different, the pages remain A4, but the layout changes, although both computers have the same resolution and dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS maintain design for both.

`@media print` - for printers

`@media screen` - for for computer screens, tablets, smart-phones etc.

```css
@media print{
   h1{
      color:red;
   }
}


@media screen{
   h1{
      color:blue;
   }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Click on "Result" in Snippet screen and press "CTRL + P".